JAR file did not connect to SQL Server / Solution found
**

I finally removed the TLSv1 from the "jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms" list in "the java.security" file.
I found the solution on here, I have tested it and it works perfectly.
Thank you all.

**
This is a little program, that connects to an SQL Server database after clicking on a button in the GUI, and checks if the connection is ok. My problem is: when running this program in NetBeans IDE it works perfectly and the connection is done without any issue, but when building this project and then launching the jar file the program doesn't connect, I have already checked all the necessary things: the classpath, the jdbc driver is there (in a lib directory) etc., also there are no errors messages shown.
All of this is in the same local machine. Here is the program:
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {            
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://MY_PC\\MYSQLSRV;database=my_database";
        String user="myuser";
        String pass="mypass";
        f = new JFrame();
        
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
            if(con != null){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Connection etablie avec succes");
            }
           
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(AuthTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex.getMessage());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Pas de connection");
        }   
    }   


Tell us about the classpath and how and where you set it

Everything was set automatically when building the project with netbeans, and when I verified the manifest.mf file, the path to the jdbc driver is correctly there.

I need these information: What is your Microsoft SQL Server version, edition (Express, Enterprise, etc.)? What is your Java/JDK version? Library and version of lib for connecting (JDBC), its file name, version of Windows operating system? Do you enable TCP/IP protocol and open firewall for port 1433 (or you use different port)? Do you enable SQL Server services?

Can you tell (1) what files are there (and the structure) of your JAR file and (2) the content of your manifest file (which is within the JAR file).

Hi @VyDo thanks for your response, so the machine that I am working on contains,MS SQL Server version is 'Entreprise', windows  10 Family, JDK 8, JDBC: sqljdbc41.jar for the port it is 1433( the same thing with or without mentioning it in the URL"                  for the TCP/IP protocol it is enabled, what other thing could cause the prob

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Pas de connection"); is not helping you. You should do ex.printStackTrace();

Ok, but how Can I see the error messages when launching the jar file

You can either a) run the jar at the command line or b) configure java.exe rather than javaw.exe to 'open' jars by default (which I normally do anyway - it's not good to have error output hidden from one)

That's it, I ran the jar file from the command line and I got this error:                                           « The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12] ».

So what version of SQL Server are you running? (What's the output of SELECT @@VERSION when executed in SSMS?) SQL Server has had TLS 1.2 support out-of-box since SQL Server 2016, and there were service packs and cumulative updates that enabled TLS 1.2 support for SQL Server 2008-2014. Sounds like you're going through all this pain because you've installed a really old version and forgotten to install subsequent updates.

Thank you for you reaction, you are right, as I edited in my question, the problem was in the TLS Protocole, the server where asking to use tls 1.0 and the jre preferences were tls 1.2 and 1.3 so I have to remove the tls 1.0 from the disabled Algorithms list in the java.security file and the problem was solved.

While that has stopped your errors, it's not really the solution. You really should install all pending service packs and cumulative updates that are available for your SQL Server as, besides adding features like TLS 1.2 support, they provide numerous bug fixes, security patches and performance improvements.

Another problem now, when trying to connect the same standalone jar file to a distant Ms sql server I have this error: The driver couldn't establish a secured connection with the sql server using SSL, eventhough I am not using any ssl I am using tls encryption., any idea about that?
